# Как в Django передать информацию с одной страницы на другую?

Tags: python, django

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку купить, меня перекидывает на страницу с формой обратной связи, и я хочу, чтобы на этой странице была информация о товаре, на который я нажал "купить". Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Можно Django Cache использовать, на странице, где нажимается кнопка "Купить" добавляешь информацию.

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.set('Тут ключ', 'Тут значение')
```

Ну и на странице с формой обратной связи получаешь значение по ключу. Потом удаляешь его из кеша.

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.get('Тут ключ')
cache.delete('Тут ключ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо получить данные из html для этого почитай тут все нормально расписано (https://djbook.ru/ch07s02.html)
А потом эти данные передать на другую страницу (https://djbook.ru/ch04.html)

Answer (score 0):

Например, по кнопке "Купить", записывать через ajax в сессию id товара. А при переходе на другую страницу, получать из сессии id и по нему получать необходимые данные о товаре как обычно. Правда, не уверен, что это джанговэй.